# Loading model or loading weights for a Tensorflow model results in cublas handle error when using predict method

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I trained a model and successfully used it to make a prediction, but loading model and loading weights neither work for prediction.

```py
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, input_shape=[120, 120, 1], activation='relu', padding="SAME"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=3),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='swish'),
    keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'),
]

model.compile(
  optimizer='nadam',
  loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
  metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

When training is done, I tried both `.save()` and `.save_weights()` and then loaded either the full model or weights on a new instance of the model, both fail to make any prediction:

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node sequential_1/conv2d_1/Conv2D (defined at <input>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_864]
```

The warning is about a failure to load cublas handles:

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
```

I thought disabling GPU may help, and tried to force using CPU using this code;

```
my_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices(device_type='CPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(devices= my_devices, device_type='CPU')
```

It didn't change anything.

I use `model.save('mymodel')` and `model.save_weights('mymodel')` to save model and weights, loading them with `model.load('mymodel')` and model.load_weight('mymodel')`.

Comment: Could you somehow provide a mwe to reproduce this error, also explicit code how you save and load model / model_weights.

Comment: Added the way I saved model/weights, but not really sure how I can provide everything to reproduce the error. Is there any option to output some sort of runtime log or more detailed error?

Comment: Can you try to load it in the following way: tf.keras.models.load_model('mymodel'). If that does not work: Does saving and loading as .h5 work? So model.save('mymodel.h5'). And tf.keras.models.load_model('mymodel.h5').